# Query a relationship that is NOT part of a scope in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

For a model I have a complicated scope condition like so:

```
class Foo {
    public function scopeActive(Builder $query) {
        $dateNow = $now->format('Y-m-d');
        $timeNow = $now->second(0)->format('H:i:s');
        $query->whereNull('start_date')
            ->orWhere('start_date', '<', $dateNow)
            ->orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($dateNow, $timeNow) {
                 $query->where('start_date', '=', $dateNow)
                     ->where('start_time', '>=', $timeNow);
            });
    }
}
```

This complicated condition will select all the records in `Foo` that are considered active (the real scope is even more complicated than that).

I have another class like so:

```
class Bar {
    public function foos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Foo::class);
    }
}
```

Which means the `Bar` model has many `Foo` models.

Now if I wanted to get all the `Bar` models as well as all the active `Foo` models that belong to it, I can do the following:

```
Bar::with(['foo', function (HasMany $query) {
    $query->active();
})->get();
```

However, how can I write a query that gives me all the `Bar` records that are NOT active.

Ideally I would want something like this:

```
Bar::with(['foo', function (HasMany $query) {
    $query->whereNot(function (Builder $query) {
        $query->active();
    });
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be an *efficient* way to easily invert SQL using Laravel for complicated queries.

You just gotta have to write the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a scope that does the opposite, just create another scope method like so, but with inverted query logic (you didn't include your 'Some complicated query', so this is just a guess):

```
public function scopeInactive($query) {
    return $query->where('is_active', false);
}
```

[Laravel: local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: I edited it slightly to give an idea of the complicated scope. The real one is even more complex. Hence I don't want to repeat it all over again

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to invert scopes. That means you'll have to write the exact same complicated query, but with inverted logic.

Comment: A better idea would be to do the following:
Add an extra attribute to your model (eg. 'is_active'). Then, setup a Schedule that regularly updates your database. For example: every hour, query all _models_ that are 'too old' and set their 'is_active' attribute to false. Then you'll be able to use a simple scope to determine whether or not your _model_ is active.

Comment: Yes but that is more complex, has more overhead and can mean the database give incorrect results when it hasn't updated yet.

Comment: Exactly, but I think you only have those two options. I would personally choose the latter option. Complicated queries will increase page load time. Running the same query in the background will avoid such problems. You could run the schedule command every minute or so to get pretty accurate results.